# Android AlertDialog

Tags: android, dialog

If I take this code and put it in a method I can't get it visible.
Could someone help me with this problem?

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")

           .setCancelable(false)

           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
              {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
               {
                    Activity.this.finish();

               }

           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
               {

                    dialog.cancel();
               }

           });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

    alert.show();
```

Comment: Inside which class is this code, i.e. what references this (MainSleepActivity?)? From which class inherits the conaining class? Do you execute this code on an UI thread or on a worker thread?

Comment: the code seems correct. try creating and returning the dialog in onCreateDialog(int id) by overriding it. then use showDialog(id) when you want to actually show the dialog. if that does not work still, please list any errors that you might see on the logcat.

Comment: how do i create it in a onCreateDialog?

Comment: @Sebastin: Look at the answer section on how to create the dialog using onCreateDialog. You basically have to override onCreateDialog in your class that extends Activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
private final static int DIALOG_XYZ = 0;

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_XYZ:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Activity.this.finish();
                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });
            Dialog alert = builder.create();
            return alert;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then when you want to show the dialog (from where-ever, just do -

```
showDialog(DIALOG_XYZ);
```

Note: As @Hyberboreus hinted, you cannot show the alert dialog on a non-UI thread such as another thread that is running or a service, etc. If that is something you want, look at AsyncTask examples available on the developer's site that tell you how to synchronize background threads with the UI threads and update the UI. HTH.